# Update model on hyperledger composer rest server

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have running my composer-rest-server script with my model deployed.
Now I want to add new assets to this model, so I deploy a new model, but if I execute composer-rest-server to create a new API REST for the new model I got an error of address in use, which is normal because this address and port (3000) is in use for the old deployed model...

Can I update the rest server with the new model?

Answer (score 0):

Simply stop the existing `composer-rest-server` process to release the port, typically using CTRL-C. Alternatively you can use the -P option to specify the port that the `composer-rest-server` should use.

Comment: Proper approach to update a bna in hyperledger :  https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/upgrading-bna